# Blender not showing whole images

Tags: interface

Blender is not completely drawing images. The 3D viewport itself works fine, but many of the other features are not working.
I will begin by showing images of the issue. At the bottom I describe my settings and system.

[image: partial splashscreen]
For example, the splash screen only shows half the image.
[image: A fully-rendered image]
[image: The saved image from the rendered scene]
This image has finished rendering (As visible from the saved image), but only a portion of it shows in the viewport. The second image is just the image itself, not a screenshot.
[image: Node Editor Missing images]
Finally, the node editor is missing images and even entire nodes.

[image: System Settings]
I've attached my system settings if anyone has any ideas about what may help.

I am running Arch Linux under the Nouveau drivers. Everything is completely up to date. I've already looked at this [thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=163017), over on the arch linux forums, and the fix was to switch to the Nvidia proprietary drivers. Unfortunately, those drivers fail to run on my card properly (I've got a dual gpu card which is not correctly supported and so it only uses one GPU which immediately dies under the weight and shuts off the computer) so that isn't an option. Has anyone seen this and come up with a solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this is driver issue… You can try to tweak OGL settings in UserPreferences, System tab (change drawmodes, remove any multisample, etc.), but there is no guarantee you'll be able to get working this way.

Comment: The Nouveau drivers don't work for CUDA, you have to use the Nvidia proprietary drivers.

Comment: This older question, was  off-topic on Blender SE. Any answer will in longer be useful in any case,  so it  has been closed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same on a old Dell notebook with Nvidia Geforce GO 7950 and Nouveau driver.

I managed to get the full images shown by selecting *DrawPixels* as *Image Draw Method* in user preferences.